# Counting the number of common elements between two arraylists - Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to see how many common elements two array lists have. This is the code I've come up with but this unfortunately returns: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Here is the code:

```
private int score(int correctAnswers){ 
    correctAnswers = 0;

    Collections.addAll(quiz1Answers, "ottawa", "toronto", "tokyo", "northamerica", "seoul", "Asia", "unitedstates", "50");
    Collections.addAll(quiz1UserAnswers, "ottawa", "dfdf", "tokyo", "northamerica", "seoul", "x", "unitedstates", "50");

    for (int i = 0; i <= quiz1Answers.size(); i++)
    {
        if (quiz1Answers.contains(quiz1UserAnswers.get(i)))
        {
            correctAnswers++;

        }
    } 
    return correctAnswers;
}
```

How would I go about solving this?

EDIT: Here is the full error messsage:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at Quiz1.score(Quiz1.java:309)
at Quiz1.jButton4ActionPerformed(Quiz1.java:364)
at Quiz1.access$400(Quiz1.java:16)
at Quiz1$5.actionPerformed(Quiz1.java:148)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Consider providing the full stack trace, as the error is meaningless

Comment: Looks fine to me, you might want to take a close look at where the exception occurs.

Comment: The error also implies some sort of GUI is involved, which was not mentioned .

Comment: Your loop looks backwards, you are using `i <= quiz1Answers.size()`, but access the `quiz1UserAnswers` collection with `quiz1UserAnswers.get(i)`, there's no gurentee that the two collections are the same size...

Comment: <= size() should probably be < size()

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8` You try to access index 8 of a collection that has a highest index of 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `ArrayList` is indexable from 0 to size() - 1, when you access the element at index size() you are out of bounds.

```
for (int i = 0; i < quiz1Answers.size(); i++) // not <=
```

From the [`ArrayList.get(int index)` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) (bold added),

> Throws:
>
> if the index is out of range (index < 0 || **index >= size()**)

Also, your if condition appears incorrect and you should test that the index isn't outside second collection's range,

```
if (quiz1UserAnswers.size() < i && quiz1UserAnswers.get(i).equals(quiz1Answers.get(i)))
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'm still new to Java (and programming) so I appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Could also mention that the OP is indexing the loop through the `quiz1Answers` collection while retrieving elements from `quiz1UserAnswers` - It would be better to use `quiz1UserAnswers.contains(quiz1Answers.get(i))` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Are you sure? Usually a test answer should be isomorphic to the question. C should not be correct if any answer is C. Unless of course C is the correct answer for a particular question. :)

Comment: Your example isn't wrong, it's just long winded (IMHO), where using something like `quiz1UserAnswers.contains(quiz1Answers.get(i))` reduces the number of checks needed (to one instead of two) and solves both problems. This is just my opinion, but I think it's more readable. If you teach someone to shoot, you not only teach them which way to hold the gun, but also the direction, so they don't shoot themselves (or you) in the foot ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer My point is "ottawa" is presumably only correct for question 1, using contains the respondent might have every answer in an incorrect order. Given OP's specific inputs that may not matter, but it is an important distinction. Swapping northamerica and asia is a pretty serious error on a geography test.